# Change kernel on Ubuntu live cd

Tags: live-cd

I was trying to boot my Ubuntu studio live cd but my video card is incompatible and freezes the boot. Last time I added something to the kernel like noboot something to bypass checking for the video card allowing me to get in but I can't remember what it was!

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title and please don't add your answer as an edit to the question. Write your answer as a separate post in the space below.

Comment: Sure, sorry didnt realise. done and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I finally remembered, by adding NOMODESET to my kernel boot I am able to bypass the video driver check and get into the live cd.